# Normal subgroups and $xH=Hx$ in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

In Lang's Algebra (3rd Ed.) §3 p.13 he writes:

> Let $f:G \to G'$ be a group-homomorphism, and let $H$ be its kernel. If $x$ is an element of G, then $xH=Hx$, because both are equal to $f^{-1} (f(x))$.

I can't understand his justification of this statement.

First, how do I know for sure that $f$ has an inverse? Second, it is easy to see that $f(xH)=f(Hx)$, since $H$ is $f$'s kernel, but this isn't a reason to conclude that $xH=Hx$. Is he implicitly assuming that $f$ is injective by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, he does not assume $f$'s infectivity, by $f^{-1}(\cdot)$ he denotes the inverse image operation, given for *subsets* $B \subseteq G'$ by 
$$ f^{-1}(B) := \{x \in G: f(x) \in B\} $$
For singletons, e. g. $\{f(x)\}$, he seems to omit the curly brackets, writing $f^{-1}(f(x))$ instead of the correct $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$. Now note that 
$$ y \in f^{-1}(f(x)) \iff f(y) \in \{f(x)\} \iff f(y) = f(x) $$
which happens exactly iff $yx^{-1} \in H$, that is $y \in xH$. That is $f^{-1}(f(x))= xH$. Along the same lines, one sees that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = Hx$.

Comment: it seems that you forgot the curly brackets after the words "the curly brackets" :)

Comment: Upps :) ... thx, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}(f(x))$ is talking about the elements in the pre-image of $f(x)$, so it is all the elements of $G$ which get mapped to $f(x)$.  It is not talking about the inverse function.  In fact $f$ is injective if and only if the kernel is only the identity.

Think about $f(x)=x^2$ just as a real valued function.  $f^{-1}(f(2))=f^{-1}(2^2)=f^{-1}(4)=\{-2,2 \}$